# How to send HTML emails with images that load from web pages? Ideally with Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, html, html-mail

I have this HTML email that I made with images pointing to my web page. When I insert the HTML code(Thunderbird: Insert->HTML...) or when I paste it directly into the HTML editor (Thunderbird Stationery add-on) they get attached and embeded in the email itself.

The HTML I'm inserting is

```
<img align="left" alt="" src="http://www.domainName.com/email/12_2013/images/lokosimpleg.jpg" width="564">
```

Thunderbird is set to send in Auto mode

How do I send the email so the inline images don't get attached and load from the web page instead?

Ideally OS independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add this code

```
moz-do-not-send="true"
```

So, your HTML will look like:

```
<img src="http://www.domainName.com/myImage.jpg" moz-do-not-send="true">
```

[Source](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_complex_mails_with_inline_images)

Comment: Do any email clients load images by default, or are all images blocked?

Comment: I believe it can be done yes via embedding... Not sure if it was a hack that has been fixed etc, and I can't find the citation for my claim at the moment. 
Regardless, my final answer will be, it depends on the email client. I could write one that did or didn't block...